# How to convert following method to java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have List object and I need to take the first element on the list if it is not null or empty.

I write below code using java and now I want to convert it to Java 8.

```
    List<DD> container
    A<DD,DI> a;
    if(container!=null || !container.isEmpty()){
       for(DD dd:container)
       {
          a = dd.getPrescription();
          break;
       }
    }
```

I convert it like this.

```
 DD detail = container.stream().findFirst().get();
```

I need to know this is correct?

Comment: @manfromnowhere it is want to 'orElse' part.

Comment: It is best practice to use orElse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a critical flaw in your current code, i.e.

```
if(container!=null || !container.isEmpty())
```

this can still throw a `NullPointerException` (when `container == null`), unless the conditional operator is changed to `&&`. Post which the implementation below would be what I would suggest following.

---

It's almost correct, in the sense that you need to handle some default value  if the conditions are not met :

```
DD detail = container.stream().findFirst().orElse(null); // or some default value instead of 'null'
```

If the `container` itself could be null, use

```
DD detail = container != null ? 
                container.stream().findFirst().orElse(null) : null;
```

---

In the case when you need the prescription from this object, use `map` as :

```
container.stream().findFirst().map(DD::getPrescription).orElse(null)
//                               ^^
//                               return type of prescription then
```

---

With Java-9, this could have been much simpler as :

```
A<DD, DI> basePrescription = Stream.ofNullable(container) // Java-9 API
                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .map(DD::getPrescription)
                                   .orElse(null);
```

Comment: `container` can be null as per OP's original code. You might want to change this to `detail = container != null ? container.stream().findFirst().orElse(<someDefaultValue>) : <someDefaultValue>;` or do a regular null check

Comment: as i understand 'container!=null || !container.isEmpty()' this condition , is check above code ?

Comment: @nullpointer i decide it write like this ' A<DD,DI> basePrescription = container != null ? container.stream().findFirst().map(DD::getPrescription).orElse(null) : null;
  ' are there any way to further simplify this ?

Comment: @uma not much i could think of currently with Java-8 and those possibilities of `null`. Edited to include a cleaner java-9 solution as well though.

Comment: @nullpointer ' ' A<DD,DI> basePrescription = container != null ? container.stream().findFirst().map(DD::getPrescription).orElse(null) : null;' in this code , if container is not null,but what happen is it empty ?

Comment: @uma If its empty the branch to follow would be `container.stream()...` no elements hence `findFirst` returns `Optional.empty` and hence `orElse(null)` comes into picture.. in short it would return `null`.

Answer (score 5):

This is way easier:

```
A<DD,DI> a = container.get(0).getPrescription();
```

While this is a direct translation of your original code, you probably intended something like that:

```
A<DD,DI> a = container != null && !container.isEmpty()
    ? container.get(0).getPrescription()
    : null;
```

Comment: They are non-functional. `container.isEmpty()` will throw. But I assumed OP knows how to do null checks.

Answer (score 4):

As of JDK9, there is a new method **[T requireNonNullElse(T obj,
                                       T defaultObj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-)** which essentially returns the first argument if it is non-null and otherwise returns the non-null second argument.

We can, therefore, simplify your code to:

```
Objects.requireNonNullElse(container, Collections.emptyList())
       .stream()
       .findFirst()
       .map(DD::getPrescription);
```

This returns an [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) where `T` is whatever type `getPrescription` is. depending on the context and whether it's appropriate you might want to use `.orElse(null);` to get the value the optional contains or else a `null` value but there are also several other methods in the [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) API which you might find more useful when extracting the value from the optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
The findFirst() method finds the first element in a Stream. This method is used when you specifically want the first element from a sequence.

a) container.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
b) container.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);
c)container.stream().filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).findFirst();
or as lambdas:
d)container.stream().filter(s -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)).findFirst();

e)container.stream().filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).findFirst()
```

For reference:- http://www.geekabyte.io/2015/01/using-optional-effectively-in-java-8.html